# for TDD of viewController created programmatically - related queries

Tags: ios, swift, tdd

for TDD of viewController: 
ViewController is also created programmatically (by writing tests first, making it fail and then creating it, to make tests pass)

i have subviews/UI components of viewcontroller defined through coding. (not by IBOutlet from storyboard or Nib)

i have following queries:

1) checking if subview is added to superview or not 
2) checking if constraint applied properly or not
3) checking if UIView component expected properties (like font, color, border, corner radius) applied properly or not.

should it be part of Unit tests or UI tests?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of tests should be part of UI-tests. However, it you want to test if UI is properly layout -> Have a look at snapshot-tests as well. (e.g. Developed by Facebook and lately Uber -> https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case)